# How to display images from same item from a data collection in a slider gallery

Tags: velo

I am trying to build a simple website which will display several images of a large number of items.

Every item has at least 5 images in seperate fields. I stored them in a collection. And there will be hundreds of items.

Repeaters and galleries shows images from every item from the SAME field.

What I want is to show 5 images of the SAME item in a slider gallery and when I click on next button we will see the 5 images of the next item.

How can I do this? (I am not a very skilled Wix user).Here is an image of my collection:

[image]

I tried to build a gallery from scratch but can not find documentation for that.
I tried referencing databases, it did not work and seems not s good idea.

I expect someona who has experience in Wix collections can guide me to the correct workflow.

Thank you.